# Nissan Qashqai acceleration issue

Tags: nissan, acceleration, qashqai

My Nissan runs fine until I hit around 50mph then it feels like it is limiting my speed. Accelerating feels like it does when I activate the speed limiting option. It eventually gets me past 50mph but lags. I'm due a service, but other than that, there are no warning lights on?
Thanks in advance for any information,
Faye

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!